# Ethernet connectivity issues | Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and cannot get connectivity via Ethernet, every time I try to connect it, it disconnects due to timeout I guess.

Some info may help I guess:

```
carlos@EQUIPO:~$ ifconfig

enp1s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f8:a9:63:73:6b:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1400  bytes 205543 (205.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Bucle local)
        RX packets 4968  bytes 373829 (373.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4968  bytes 373829 (373.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.129  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::6f54:39ce:cf5b:1ca0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:ee:65:87:21:e9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6503  bytes 6727242 (6.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5769  bytes 829315 (829.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any extra information that may be needed, just ask for it. Thank you :)

Comment: I changed your quote format `"` to code block format `{}` because it is easier to read.

Comment: Did you try a different Ethernet cable? Does it work in Windows?

Comment: I have Win10 and Ubuntu here and the Ethernet cable is not a problem...